# Why sed doesn't work?

Tags: unix, sed, replace, sh, space

I have a file named test.sh 
here is the content inside test.sh:

```
LC_ALL=C zgrep -hoi "an unexpected EOF" /data/log/test.log.gz >> temp.txt
```

I would like to replace `"an unexpected EOF"` with `"App_UnhandledException"`

I would also like to replace `temp.txt` with `tempEOF.txt`

I tried this command but it seems not working. After I run the command, I didn't see anything replaced

```
sed -i 's/an unexpected EOF/App_UnhandledException/g' test.sh
```

What's wrong with my command?

Comment: can you show an exemplary line containing `"an unexpected EOF"` from your file?

Comment: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.    at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

Comment: Try to add the -e switch.

Comment: sed -i -- 's/temp/tempEOF/g' test.sh works, it replace temp.txt to tempEOF.txt, but I don't know why the string with space doesn't work.

Comment: how to add -e? sed -ie?

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/....`

Comment: cool, it works!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte would you like to make that an answer?

Comment: @spspli -- I'm curious which Unix are you using? Usually *sed* would take the first non-option argument as the script if there's no `-e` or `-f`.

Comment: `-i` takes an *optional* argument, so treats the word following it as the extension, not a script.